# failed to install ruby with rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, rbenv

I followed this video: [for how to install ruby](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jx0NrIbQbzI). But then I couldn't install ruby. There are some other people as well with such kind of [issue](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/issues/736#issue-63587267). Please help me to fix it. Thanks.

```
rbenv install 2.2.1
Downloading ruby-2.2.1.tar.gz...
->     http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/5a4de38068eca8919cb087d338c0c2e3d72c9382c804fb27ab746e6c7819ab28
Installing ruby-2.2.1...

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.10.2 using ruby-build 20150319zf)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at             /var/folders/c8/tr13g20944g8jymgp72wz7pw0000gn/T/ruby-build.20150326002550.58440
Results logged to /var/folders/c8/tr13g20944g8jymgp72wz7pw0000gn/T/ruby-build.20150326002550.58440.log

Last 10 log lines:
                          psych 2.0.8
                          rake 10.4.2
                          rdoc 4.2.0
./tool/rbinstall.rb:714:in `rescue in block in <main>': uninitialized constant LoadErroe (NameError)
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:712:in `block in <main>'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:757:in `call'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:757:in `block in <main>'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:754:in `each'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:754:in `<main>'
make: *** [do-install-all] Error 1
```

Comment: Try installing 2.0.0-p576 first.

Comment: @liyicky how to install 2.0.0-p576? Its older version right

Comment: Yeah, try this: rbenv install 2.0.0-p576

Comment: @liyicky it worked know what? How can i install the latest version?

Comment: Do you need the latest version? If you don't need it I would recommend staying with 2.0 or 2.1